# Subtract value from group of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Year          Month    Code         Value
2021        January     201         100.00
2021        February    201         250.00
2021        January     202         300.00
2021        February    202         200.00
2021        March       201         50.00
2021        March       202         150.00
```

Need to subtract code 201 from 202 , grouping both code by month.
Output :

```
Year     Month     Value 
2021    january     200 
2021    february    -50
2021     March       100
```

I was trying to get desired output but its not working..

```
SELECT Code,Value
    ,
    (
        SELECT sum(Value) as Value
        FROM [TestD]
        Where Code = '202'
        GROUP BY Code
        )-(
        SELECT sum(Value) as Value
        FROM [TestD]
        where Code = '201'
        GROUP BY Code
        )  AS item_total

FROM [TestD] group by Code,Value
```

Comment: Please do not spam the tag. `MySQL` <> `SQL Server`. `tsql` <> `plsql`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression inside `sum(...)`, with `group by Year, Month`:

```
select Year, 
Month,
sum(case when Code = '201' then -Value when Code = '202' then Value end) as Value
from TestD
group by Year, Month
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dad99d15bac9866e58af25288a2b7dea)

Comment: Actually i need to subtract code 201 (group by month ) from code 202 (group by month )

Comment: @Vats check the fiddle link, see if that's the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this provided only 2 values are going to be subtracted

```
declare @tbl table (year int, [month] varchar(50),code int, [value] int)

insert into @tbl values(2021, 'January', 201, 100.00),(2021, 'Feb', 201, 250.00)
,(2021, 'January', 202, 300.00),(2021, 'Feb', 202, 200.00)


select year,[month],[value], row_number()over(partition by [month] order by [value] desc) rownum
into #temp
from @tbl

select year,
month
,case when rownum = 1 then value else (
(select value from #temp t1 where t1.[month] = t.[month] and t1.rownum = 1) - 
value) end as diff
from #temp t
where t.rownum = 2
order by month desc

drop table #temp
```